# Recycleview Duplicate from Firebase Database

Tags: duplicates

I'm having an issue with RecyclerView, I tried so many different ways, and I think my code is clean enough. but the item still duplicated everytime I reach 5 nodes from recyclerView. Never mind with the date because it is not coded yet.

Here's my RecyclerView

```
    private void initializeRecyclerView(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView mHistoryList = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mHistoryList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mHistoryList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mStoreListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mHistoryList.setLayoutManager(mStoreListLayoutManager);
    mHistoryListAdapter = new HistoryListAdapter(arrayList, History.this);
    mHistoryList.setAdapter(mHistoryListAdapter);
}
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class HistoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
ArrayList<HistoryObject> arrayList;
Context mContext;

public HistoryListAdapter(ArrayList<HistoryObject> arrayList, Context mContext){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_order_history, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String order1 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction1();
    String order2 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction2();
    String order3 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction3();
    String order4 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction4();
    String order5 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction5();
    String order6 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction6();
    String order7 = arrayList.get(position).getTransaction7();

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    if (order1 != null){
        holder.mOrder1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder1.setText(order1);
    }
    if (order2 != null){
        holder.mOrder2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder2.setText(order2);
    }
    if (order3 != null){
        holder.mOrder3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder3.setText(order3);
    }
    if (order4 != null){
        holder.mOrder4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder4.setText(order4);
    }
    if (order5 != null){
        holder.mOrder5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder5.setText(order5);
    }
    if (order6 != null){
        holder.mOrder6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder6.setText(order6);
    }
    if (order7 != null){
        holder.mOrder7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mOrder7.setText(order7);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mDate;
    public TextView mOrder1;
    public TextView mOrder2;
    public TextView mOrder3;
    public TextView mOrder4;
    public TextView mOrder5;
    public TextView mOrder6;
    public TextView mOrder7;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_history_date);
        mOrder1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_one);
        mOrder2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_two);
        mOrder3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_three);
        mOrder4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_four);
        mOrder5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_five);
        mOrder6 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_six);
        mOrder7 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_seven);
    }
}
```

}

My Firebase and Emulator. I also tried physical device but the result is same.
[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnVnC.png)

Comment: try to add else part of every if condition which making TextView Visible

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya thanks for the comment, but it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the best solution to this question. This is really a bug from RecyclerView no matter how correct and cleans your code is, this duplicate item will always appear. and the best way to this scenario is to use String.Builder. It works like a piece of cake.

```
    DatabaseReference historyReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Contract.ContractTable.DB_HISTORY)
        .child(myDBUserID)
        .child(clientID);
    historyReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            arrayList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                if (childSnapshot.child("transaction1").getValue() != null){
                    String transaction1 = (String) childSnapshot.child("transaction1").getValue();
                    stringBuilder.append(transaction1);
                }
                if (childSnapshot.child("transaction2").getValue() != null){
                    String transaction2 = (String) childSnapshot.child("transaction2").getValue();
                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(transaction2);
                }
                if (childSnapshot.child("transaction3").getValue() != null){
                    String transaction3 = (String) childSnapshot.child("transaction3").getValue();
                    stringBuilder.append("\n").append(transaction3);
                }
                String collectiveData = String.valueOf(stringBuilder);
                HistoryObject historyObject = new HistoryObject(collectiveData);
                arrayList.add(historyObject);
            }
            mHistoryListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```